# How to create share functionality in Android

Tags: android, uri, share

I need some ideas: I have a *quiz app*.

When user has done a quiz, i wont to let him share the quiz he has already done to his friends, so they can't take the same quiz and compare results.

How can i implement such share?

I was wondering about implementing my own url scheme, but i've read that it isn't a good idea. I haven't a website atm, so i would like to handle everything from android.

Thanks

Edit: Sorry for not being accuratly with what i was asking
My problem is not the share function (i know i van easily do it with shareactionprovider).
My problem is how can a user after seeing his friend's message, open my app and open the same quiz?
I can think about: using a search function or implement my own uri scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple choice for this. 
First one is implementing Facebook's [api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) as below

```
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Open share dialog via facebook app

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink(".......")
            .setApplicationName("..........")
            .setCaption("...........")
            .setDescription("...............")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Another option is to implement [ShareActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html) class of Android.